# Como pegar a URL atual do Browser com o PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-routes

Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte URL gerada com o `ngRoute` do `AngularJS`: `https://www.projeto.com/edit/25`, o 25 é o ID, preciso pegar este ID no PHP.

Em pesquisas, encontrei a seguinte solução para pegar a URL no PHP:

`$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`

Porém o problema é que ele retorna a URL errada, retorna `https://www.projeto.com/edita.php` em vez da URL gerada pelo angular (`https://www.projeto.com/edit/25`).

> Existe alguma forma de pegar a URL atual do browser no php?

Comment: Dê um print_r($_SERVER) e veja as opções que o servidor lhe dispõe. Acredito que o valor que deseja estará na listagem.

Comment: @BrunoRigolon Obrigado! Lá tem a opção `HTTP_REFERER` que é exatamente o que preciso. Põe como resposta na pergunta. :)

Comment: Seria muito interessante também você postar aqui as regras do .htaccess para a reescrita da URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o atributo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], ele fará referência ao link de origem da solicitação.

Comment: Só lembrando que isso é perigoso, nunca confie nos cabeçalhos, qualquer um pode alterar essa informação. Inclusive muitos plugins/extensões de privacidade nem sequer enviam essa informação.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @Inkeliz